# How to identify Windows 10 background store processes that have non-displayed windows that are programmatically visible and minimizable?

Tags: windows, winapi, desktop

I have a Win32 application that determines whether there are any visible, non-iconic, minimizable windows being shown. To the best of my knowledge it's worked fine for Win9x through to Win8.1, but under Windows 10 it often finds several windows that aren't actually visible on the screen.

To try to identify what's going on I've written a simple test application that enumerates and records all such windows. Here's the essence of the EnumWindows callback code:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumFunc( HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam )
{
  if ( IsWindowVisible( hWnd ) )
  {
    if ( !IsIconic( hWnd ) )
    {
      const LONG style = GetWindowLong( hWnd, GWL_STYLE );

      if ( WS_MINIMIZEBOX & style )
      {
     //      record window info
      }
    }
   }
 return TRUE;
}
```

Most of the phantom windows under Windows 10 belong to background store app processes such as Mail, Calculator, and Photos. These are listed under the Background processes section of Task Manager, and if I use Task Manager to end those background tasks, their phantom window is no longer found by my test application.

[image]

In the above screen shot from my test application you can see that all but 1 of the offending windows belong to threads of the same process id 7768, which is ApplicationFrameHost.exe. The final window with process id 11808 is explorer.exe.

I've looked at the phantom windows with Spy++ and can't see any particular style combination that would help in uniquely identifying them.

I've had a suggestion that the undocumented Windows "bands" may be involved, but I've tried using the (undocumented, so this may be wrong) API:

```
BOOL WINAPI GetWindowBand (HWND hWnd, PDWORD pdwBand);
```

but it returns a band of 1 for any window, so doesn't differentiate these phantoms.

How to reliably identify these phantom windows?

Comment: Do those windows happen to share the same window class? Or maybe have the same properties set (see [EnumProps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633562.aspx))? When you say that *"the undocumented API [...] returns a band of 1"*, which value are looking at? The `BOOL` return value, or the `DWORD` pointed to by the second parameter?

Comment: Many (not all that I've encountered) have the same window class name, but when the applications are running normally visible on screen, they still have the same class name.

Comment: Regarding the GetWindowBand call, the BOOL return value is always non-zero, and the "band" number in the DWORD pointer param is always 1.

Comment: So the phantom windows have the WS_VISIBLE style?  If so they should be visible. What are their coordinates according to Spy?  Maybe they are beyond the physical screen(s)?

Comment: Hi David, Yes, the phantom's have WS_VISIBLE, but they aren't visible. Their positions vary, some may have 0x0 rectangles, others appear to be on-screen co-ordinates. I'll try to add a screen shot to show an example of what my test program records when there are no visible windows on screen.

Comment: I apparently don't have enough "reputation" to post an image here. I have posted an example here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/1aac1a91-d839-48b1-9cf8-dbae28926e09/background-store-processes-have-nondisplayed-visible-toplevel-windows-under-windows-10-how-do-you?forum=windowsuidevelopment#1aac1a91-d839-48b1-9cf8-dbae28926e09 though from that one they all have the same class - which isn't the full story.

Comment: Since everything looks like those windows should be visible, but aren't, have you tried querying for the desktop the windows belong to ([GetWindowThreadProcessId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522.aspx), [GetThreadDesktop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683232.aspx))? Closely related to the previous, have you tried [EnumDesktopWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682615.aspx) in place of [EnumWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, I perhaps should have mentioned that I do log the return from GetThreadDesktop and the phantom windows return the same value as real windows do. The results from using EnumDesktopWindows is the same as EnumWindows.

Comment: If anyone's interested in trying the test application, I've put the project sources (VS2015) here: http://1drv.ms/1PrVd2c

Comment: @DavidLowndes:  How do you get e.g. Mail to be a background process?  For me, either it doesn't appear in Task Manager at all (it's not running) or it appears in the top Apps section (not Background Processes).

Comment: Hi David, I wish I knew how it occurs! I'm wondering whether it has something to do with logging on with a MS account because on a clean VM where I don't use a MS account I don't see the store apps as background items - though there is still 1 phantom non-visible "visible" window there too.

Comment: Scrub that last idea for it being logging on with a MS account - I've now done that in my test VM and try as I might, I can't get apps to appear as background apps. However, one observation is that initially there are no phantom windows, but as soon as I start a single app there's the 1 phantom window.

Answer (score 16):

The approved way of detecting these phantom windows is to use DwmGetWindowAttribute and DWMWA_CLOAKED.

Here's the code I've used:

```
static bool IsInvisibleWin10BackgroundAppWindow( HWND hWnd )
{
    int CloakedVal;
    HRESULT hRes = DwmGetWindowAttribute( hWnd, DWMWA_CLOAKED, &CloakedVal, sizeof( CloakedVal ) );
    if ( hRes != S_OK )
    {
        CloakedVal = 0;
    }
    return CloakedVal ? true : false;
}
```

Thanks to Scot Br from MS for posting the answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f8341376-6015-4796-8273-31e0be91da62/difference-between-actually-visible-and-not-visiblewhich-are-there-but-we-cant-see-windows-of?forum=vcgeneral)

Comment: Windows in another desktop will also show as DWMWA_CLOAKED. So a better way to do this is to use this library: 

https://github.com/Grabacr07/VirtualDesktop

Use VirtualDesktop.FromHwnd() method, and if it's null, that means it's a Windows 10 Background app.

`return VirtualDesktop.FromHwnd(hWnd) == null;`

Comment: @AfzalivE thanks!! I use Grabacr07's code in my project. https://github.com/mzomparelli/zVirtualDesktop

Comment: @MichaelZ. That's great! That looks like something I'm making too lol

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing your tool. Do you have it on GitHub?

Comment: Not really, don't want to open source it just yet :)

Comment: I use the C# version of the code above, and it fails to identify the background Settings app on my Win10 machine. When the machine boots, the Settings app has an `ApplicationFrameWindow` and a `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow` and is not visible in Alt-TAB. Starting and exiting the Settings app makes both windows disappear. I wish there was a reliable way to spot those UWP background apps.

Comment: This works fine. For those unaware it needs the include #include <dwmapi.h>
 and a library added:  Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies : add Dwmapi.lib, else you will get an external reference error when linking.

Comment: More info: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f8341376-6015-4796-8273-31e0be91da62/difference-between-actually-visible-and-not-visiblewhich-are-there-but-we-cant-see-windows-of?forum=vcgeneral

Answer (score 2):

Top-level windows of class `ApplicationFrameWindow` are containers for Windows Store apps. First, here is the window of Mail shown in Spy:

[image]

This is truly visible (not phantom).  You can tell that it is because the first child is a window of class `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow`.  Interestingly, the owner process of the `ApplicationFrameWindow` is `APPLICATIONFRAMEHOST`, but the owner process of the `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow` is a *different* one: HXMAIL.  (I've not seen a child window owned by a different process than the parent one before!)

Compare that with a phantom window (as identified in your `RWTool`):

[image]

It is missing the child of class `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow`.

This suggests an answer to your question:  If a top-level window is of class `ApplicationFrameWindow`, iterate it's children.  If the first child has class `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow`, the window is visible, otherwise it is not (i.e. it is phantom).

But what if an old-fashioned, non-store app happened to have a top-level window of class `ApplicationFrameWindow`?  It would not have a child of `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow`.  Yet it is visible.  How to tell this is an ordinary app and not a Windows Store app?  I don't have a foolproof way.  You could also check for the existence of the other child windows of a Store app:  `ApplicationFrameTitleBarWindow` and `ApplicationFrameInputSinkWindow`.  The chances of a non-Store app having this exact Windows hierarchy is vanishingly small.

**EDIT**

The `ApplicationFrameWindow`'s (and also `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow`) have the [WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx) style set:

> The window does not render to a redirection surface. This is for windows that do not have visible content or that use mechanisms other than surfaces to provide their visual.

At minimum, you could check for this style instead of special casing `ApplicationFrameWindow`. Though to see if any content was truly visible, you'd still need to make that depend on whether it has a child of `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow`.

Comment: Thanks David, that pattern does match what I see for the phantom store app windows, however I also see a phantom that appears for the Skype process (latest desktop version) and that one doesn't have any child windows, and has the class name "TApplication", so I don't see this sort of thing being a reliable solution.

Comment: Sure David, but I don't understand how an old-fashioned Skype app having a class name of `TApplication` invalidates the above detection of a 'phantom' Metro app vs. a 'real' Metro app?  BTW, I downloaded and installed the latest Desktop Skype onto Win 10, it is version 7.8.0.102, and the visible window with Contacts has a classname of `tSkMainForm`.  I do also find a window with class `TApplication` but the width and height are 0 so that it is not visible.

Comment: It wasn't that the Skype behaviour particularly invalidated anything, just that it indicated that the solution may not be robust because it's only based on the empirical situations that we're seeing. It does in fact work as you'd expect. I wish there was some concrete documentation that might explain what these things are and why they're not visible.

Incidentally, how did you get your Win10 system to have these non-visible app windows - I was unable to make them happen on a VM; while on my host system, they just seem to arise eventually without my doing anything!

Comment: @DavidLowndes: I'm glad it works so you can roll out a fix for your existing code.  See my Edit about WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP.  I'm sure an explanation and perhaps more comprehensive solution will be forthcoming, but this is life as a Windows dev - delivering working software to our customers without such niceties!  Ditto here for the flakiness of the phantom window appearances!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the system registers the `ApplicationFrameWindow` window class ahead of time. A non-store application will subsequently fail to register a window class with that name. So to answer your what-if question: There will not be a non-store application with a window class named `ApplicationFrameWindow`.

Comment: On my win10 desktop, I have observed 4 phantom windows - two for Photos and two for Settings. Each pair has an `ApplicationFrameWindow` AND a `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow`. So, visible windows are not always marked by the presence of a `Windows.UI.Core.Window` child. And none of the 4 windows were cloaked, either, as far as I could see (testing for cloaked returned zero in all 4 cases.)