# How can I detect that window (class Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow) is visible on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, winapi, uwp, visibility

I have a problem to verify the visibility for windows on Windows 10. The problem exists on some windows components such as Action Center, Notifications, People etc (All of them are Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow).

I tried to use methods from winapi:

- IsWindowVisible -> for these window the method alvays returns
  true(when window is visible and invisible)
- GetWindowRect -> for the notification window, when it is visible I get correct size, after hiding the height is 1px. Other windows have
  the same size and position all the time.
- GetWindowLong -> I tried to get window styles
  but this all windows have the same styles all time (WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE |
  WC_CLIPSIBLINGS) and extension styles (WS_EX_LEFT | WS_EX_LTRREADING |
  WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR | WS_EX_TOPMOST).
- GetWindowPlacement -> all the time field flag = 0 -> SW_HIDE

Does anyone have an idea how can I correctly verify the visibility of these windows?

Comment: Because return true, when Action Center/Notifications/etc window are invisible on desktop

Comment: the location of the window with handle matches the position when the window is visible (Confirmed by spy ++/getWindowsRect). The name of the window (get by GetWindowText / spy++) also agrees

Comment: this is [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33577647/6401656)

Comment: `DwmGetWindowAttribute(hwnd, DWMWA_CLOAKED, &CloakedVal, sizeof( CloakedVal ))` returned `DWM_CLOAKED_SHELL` in `CloakedVal` - *The window was cloaked by the Shell.*

Comment: also look for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23180386/6401656)