# How to get window handler (of another program) from Process ID or Process Name?

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm making a program to show another program fullscreen programmatically. To do this, I use `MoveWindow()` from WinAPI, but it needs a Window Handler. I tried to get it using `FindWindow()`, but since it uses the window name, I often had situations where the name was in a different language and it didn't work (or it didn't exist at all). So now I need to somehow get the Window Handler of the desired program by PID or even more conveniently by the name of the process. In C++, I found `EnumWindows()`, but I completely don't understand how to rewrite it in C#.

**Question: How do I get the Window Handler using the PID or the program name?**

Comment: [FindWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindoww) doesn't just search by window title.

Comment: A handle is a process number for a window control that is a child of the PID .  So you can use PPID (Parent Process ID) to find child processes

Comment: @jdweng understood. Can you, please, give some example of using it?

Comment: @jdw That doesn't make **any** sense. A handle is an opaque type used to reference some other data. A window is accessed through its `HWND`, for example. A process ID is a handle-like value that can be used to identify a process. There is no relationship between a PID and an `HWND` whatsoever, most certainly not a parent-child relationship.

Comment: @IInspectable : Did you ever compare the handle numbers against the process numbers?

Comment: @jdw No. Comparing an `HWND` value against a PID value is an utterly meaningless operation.

Comment: @jdweng: You are mixing process HANDLE and HWND, this is not same.

Comment: @user2120666 : Aren't the two using the same set of numbers?  They are both processes but of different types.

Comment: @jdweng: No this are not same. Sure, both are DWORD aligned numbers, but this is all that have same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EnumWindows` to enumerate the handles of all windows and pass the window handle as a parameter to the [GetWindowThreadProcessId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) function.

After obtaining the pid, compare the value with the pid of another program you provided. If it is the same, use `MoveWindow` to move it.

C# example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace EnumPTW
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

        // Callback Declaration
        public delegate bool EnumWindowsCallback(IntPtr hwnd, int lParam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int EnumWindows(EnumWindowsCallback callPtr, int lParam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

        public static bool ReportWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int lParam)
        {
            uint processId = 0;
            uint threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out processId);
           
            if(processId == 23272)  //23272: another program pid
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Enumerated Window Handle 0x{0:X8}, Process {1}, Thread {2}", hwnd.ToInt32(), processId, threadId));
                
                MoveWindow(hwnd, 100, 100, 800, 600, true);
            }
            
            return true;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Have to declare a delegate so that a thunk is created, so that win32 may call us back.
            EnumWindowsCallback callBackFn = new EnumWindowsCallback(ReportWindow);

            EnumWindows(callBackFn, 0);

            Console.WriteLine("Finished. Press any key to continue.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use [OpenProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess) to get the handle of the process based on the pid, then use [GetModuleFileNameEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmodulefilenameexw) to get the name of the process, and then compare the name with the process name you provided.

Sample: [The using of OpenProcess and GetModuleFileNameEx](https://gist.github.com/mmlac/67eb02b60bd0b8682c08dc61fab065f2#file-pinvoke-cs-L154)

Comment: Using the example above I end up with a lot of "junk" windows that don't exist in my explorer, how would I filter those junk windows? thx!

Comment: @Ben EnumWindows continues until the **last top-level window** is enumerated or the callback function returns FALSE.  Most of these windows are invisible, what do you want to do?

Comment: `EnumWindows` returns lots of windows that aren't visible in my Explorer. my question is how would I implement your logic above but only list actual user windows? (ones that are visible when you do shift+alt+tab for example). thx for responding!

Comment: @Ben Try [IsWindowVisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-iswindowvisible) api. It will filter  invisible windows. And, you may need do more. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53322650/11128312) should help you.